# The task in my Django asynchronous view is not executed

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-asyncio, gunicorn

Django asynchronous views can respond immediately, while tasks run asynchronously,but in fact the task cannot continue.

```
async def task_async():
    print('task begin')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('task run success')
```

```
async def view_async(request):
    print('async begin')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(task_async())
    print('return')
    return HttpResponse("Non-blocking HTTP request")
```

I expect the task to continue running after the http response returns， but the result is：

```
async begin
return
task begin
```

Using uvicron is ok, but manage.py and  daphne project.asgi:application are not, this is where i am confused, the result of uvicron ars as follows：

```
async begin
return
task begin
task run success
```

Comment: @СергейКох you're being a bit too hard on them. The question definitely can be improved, but it's not that bad for the first one, and it's quite clear what they were asking (IMO)

Comment: @СергейКох ok, i'll improve it.

Answer (score 2):

The default `manage.py runserver` command runs a [`wsgiref.simple_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server) which serves a `WSGI_APPLICATION` from your `settings.py`. Calls to async views are wrapped in `async_to_sync`, executed in a separate thread and don't have a persistent event loop.

To use ASGI during development, install Daphne server, which comes with its own `runserver` command:

```bash
$ pip install daphne
```

Edit your `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "daphne",  # <---
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    ...
]

...

ASGI_APPLICATION = "yourproject.asgi.application"  # <---
```

Now, `python manage.py runserver` should behave like you've expected.

I must add that async support in Django is primarily intended to improve performance for I/O bound code and for background tasks the better practice would be to use [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/worker.html), [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) or another task runner.

---

**EDIT:** screenshots of both `runserver` and standalone `daphne` working with the example view from the question:

[image: runserver works!]

[image: daphne works!]

Comment: I tried using daphne project.asgi:application and using managey.py as you said, but they are not as expected, but uvicron project.asgi:application is as expected, very confused about this.

Comment: Notice that in the settings value, there are two dots in the value (no colons). Also, I just double-checked to confirm it's working. Please, see attached screenshots in the answer edit. If it doesn't work for you, something else is going on and you must update your question.