# Django Asyc function execution

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, django-4.1

I am trying to execute the functions in async mode using Django DRF APIView, so that the API returns the response instantly. I am using Django 4.1.12, adrf for async View. Below is the code :

```
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from adrf.views import APIView


def sensitive_sync_function():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count = count + 1
        print("Running in Async mode !")
        time.sleep(1)
        if count == 10:
            print("Processing done !")
            break
    return None


class AsyncGroupManagementView(APIView):
    async def get(self, request, format=None):
        async_function = sync_to_async(sensitive_sync_function)
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, headers=headers)
```

The Api call executes successfully and returns response, but I am not sure if the sensitive_sync_function() executed or not as I am not able to see any logs on terminal. Do I have to explicitly execute this task later ?

My end goal is to run the function in async mode, so the API response is returned and the function keeps on executing in background. Is this the correct approach or should I use celery here ?

Any **AWS cloud based solution** for this scenario are also welcomed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery is pretty much *the tool* for the job, but if you don't want to go through the troubles of setting it up, you might get away using [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)

```py
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from adrf.views import APIView

@sync_to_async
def sensitive_sync_function():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count = count + 1
        print("Running in Async mode !")
        time.sleep(1)
        if count == 10:
            print("Processing done !")
            break
    return None


class AsyncGroupManagementView(APIView):
    async def get(self, request, format=None):
        asyncio.create_task(sensitive_sync_function())  # note the ()
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, headers=headers)
```

Notice that once `sensitive_sync_function` is running it will still block the thread. You should convert it to async and use [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) instead of `time.sleep`.

Finally, it is important that you run your app using a proper ASGI server.

To use ASGI during development, install Daphne server, which comes with its own `runserver` command:

```bash
$ pip install daphne
```

Edit your `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "daphne",  # <---
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    ...
]

...

ASGI_APPLICATION = "yourproject.asgi.application"  # <---
```

Now, `python manage.py runserver` should run the app properly.

Comment: Will this work without daphne installation on WSGI ?

Comment: @RishabhRusia it's complicated. You should use an ASGI server if you want to use async.

Comment: After creating the task, what is the process to execute this `sensitive_sync_function` function ?

Comment: I am running the service as a dockerised application and using apache/mod_wsgi. Are there any apache asgi available ?

Comment: @RishabhRusia The task will be executed in the current event loop, you don't need to do anything extra.
As for the setup, usually it's nginx + Gunicorn + uvicorn nowadays.

Comment: Is there a way to verify when are these coroutines by create_task executed. I have few loggers and print statements added to `sensitive_sync_function` function, but I don't see any logs or prints happening

Comment: Print statements should be there if you're running it using asgi. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75514866/723891 similar question I've answered a while ago, there are screenshots with things being logged. 
Since you've mentioned in the OP, If you're familiar with Celery, maybe you should use it instead and ditch async altogether @RishabhRusia

Answer (score 0):

`sync_to_async` function is basically a decorator. When you give it a function, it will return a wrapped async function.

But you're still required to execute the returned `async_function` yourself.

Now, since you mention that you want to return the response without waiting for the `async_function` to finish running. That means you can't use the `await` statement to execute it.

So, you'll have to use event loop's `create_task()` function to run the `async_function` later:

```py
async def get(self, request, format=None):
    async_function = sync_to_async(sensitive_sync_function)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # now ask the even loop to schedule your coroutine's execution
    loop.create_task(async_function())
    
    return Response(...)
```

---

Some tips:

- To execute a coroutine "right now" and wait for the result, use the `await` statement.
- To execute a coroutine a later time without waiting for it to finish, use event loop's `create_task()` function.

Comment: Will this work with WSGI ? Are there any performance impacts ?

Comment: Also, after creating the task using loop.create_task(async_function()), what is the process to execute this as I am not able to see the execution happening for `sensitive_sync_function` function ?

Comment: @RishabhRusia Yes, it will run with WSGI but with slightly worse performance. Django docs have a dedicated [Performance section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/async/#performance) about it. `create_task` will schedule the coroutine for later and execute it as well.

Comment: Is there a way to verify when are these `coroutines` by `create_task` executed. I have few loggers and print statements added to `sensitive_sync_function` function, but I don't see any logs or prints happening